# Is there a dynamic list in C that I can use to build the tree that operating systems use to store files systems?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, filesystems

I want to simulate the tree structure that operating systems use to store files in C language. But I can't link multiple child nodes under a root node using struct. As far as I know, C language doesn't have dynamic list(e.g Vectors in C++, List in Java). I don't know how to build the tree without any dynamic list.

The tree I'm trying to create;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7fvg.png)

Here is what I'm trying to do;

```
struct Node{
    char FileName[50];
    struct Node* children; 
    /*  struct Node* children1;
        struct Node* chilren2;// I want to link varying number of child nodes connecting to my parent/root node
        ..
        ..
        struct Node *children N;
    */
};

struct Node* root = NULL;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    root = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* child1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* child2 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    root -> children = child1;
//  root -> children = child2;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `children` can point to an array of Nodes. But you also need to know the size of the array. Since you might not know the number of nodes up front, you might need `realloc` to grow the array.

Comment: Operating systems typically use linked lists to store variable-length collections.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by modifying the Node structure to contain a `children` and `siblings` pointer as follows:

```
struct Node{
    char FileName[50];
    struct Node* children;
    struct Node* siblings;
};
```

The `siblings` object could be used to point to objects at the same level and the `children` object would be used to point to the first object in the list below the object.

Shown visually:
[image]